# How can I create a multiple choice prompt in picocli?

Tags: picocli

I'm trying to create a cli with a option prompt, like the image below.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

PicoCLI is not meant to do that. It's a CLI library, not a Interactive Console library as you expect it to be.

You better have to use [JAnsi](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi) and [JLine](https://github.com/jline/jline3).

Or [ConsoleUI](https://github.com/awegmann/consoleui) which should be exactly what you are looking for.